# JSONObject Serialization Emojis

Tags: java, json, eclipse, encoding, emoji

I am making calls to Instagram API like this

```
URL url = new URL("https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/tagToBeSearched/media/recent?access_token=MyToken");
URLConnection conection= url.openConnection();
conection.connect();
BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
String line = bin.readLine();
```

The `line` variable contains the response by the Instagram API as a `String`. When debugging, i noticed some special characters are in this format: `\u00f3`.

When i serialize the response to `JSONObject`, like `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(line);`, the special characters change, in this case, `\u00f3` would transform to `ó`. But with some emojis the transfomation is not always the espected emoji, like this `\uD83D\uDE03`, the equivalent of the smiley emoji (), turns into ߘ.

I am also using [emoji-java](https://github.com/vdurmont/emoji-java) to manipulate emojis, it supports using the `\ud83d\ude4c` format, so I am able to use the `parseToAliases` to get the alias of the emoji, like this:`EmojiParser.parseToAliases("\ud83d\ude4c");` Gives `:raised_hands:`, the  emoji. But if I use this after the `JSONObject` parsing, the emoji turns into ߘ and I can't get any information with `EmojiParser.parseToAliases` method.

I am using Eclipse IDE and viewing the results in the expressions window while debugging, is this because the IDE can't show the emojis and the values are still correct? Or something to do with `JSONObject` parsing? Or with the UTF-8 in the `InputStreamReader` constructor? I would like to keep the `\u00f3` format and continue using the emoji-java.

**EDIT:** Ok, i tested calling the `EmojiParser.parseToAliases()` passing the `JSONObject` response and the result is the expected format, `:raised_hands:`. I Guess i was passing the ߘ (Copy and paste in the expressions window) directly in the `EmojiParser.parseToAliases()`, doing that return the same input: ߘ

Comment: It's quite likely it is an issue with display than anything else. You should try writing an [MCVE] to verify this (and also include the details of your environment in your question - java version, libraries, versions of libraries, etc). One simple thing you can try is just printing an emoji from a string literal into the expression window and seeing what happens.

Comment: Ok, made a new test here calling the `EmojiParser.parseToAliases()` passing the emojis directly in the code, it gives back in the `:raised_hands:` format. Its problably the IDE that can't show those emojis

Answer (score 0):

When debugging Java the emojis are **displayed incorrect but the values are still correct**: see [Eclipse bug 407857](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=407857)

Comment: Yeah, i did a few tests passing the value from `JSONObject` direclty to the `EmojiParser.parseToAliases()` and received the expected value. While debugging i was testing with the value eclipse shows, not return of the method, that made me believe that something was wrong with the `JSONObject` serialization. I should probably close the question now

Comment: @LucasPalmaStabile For details see the linked Eclipse bug (I was also able to reproduce the issue). If you like, you could vote for the bug or add your e-mail to CC to track progress on this issue.